# How to obtain and pass the value of a button

Tags: android

I want to know how I can obtain the value of a button and then use it on another activity to display content accordingly.

Example:

I have 3 buttons **Image1**, **Image2** & **Image3** on my MainActivity.

Now based on what button the user clicks (**Image1**, **Image2** & **Image3**), a corresponding image is displayed on a new activity.

I know how to create these buttons, the new activity and also how to display an image on the new activity. How do I display the image based on what button the user clicks?

Comment: Is your image from drawable folder?

Comment: Yes. The images are in the drawable folder.

Answer (score 5):

Your class should implement OnClickListener  and override onClick()

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(this));
button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(this));
button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(this));


 @Override
 public void onClick(View v){

switch(v.getId()) //get the id which is an int
    {
     case R.id.button1 : //if its button1 that is clicked
         Intent i= new Intent("com.example.secondActivity");
         i.puExtra("key",value);
         startActivity(i);
        // use intents to pass information to secondActivity and display the image there
      break;
      case R.id.button2 :
         Intent i= new Intent("com.example.secondActivity");
         startActivity(i)
         //use intents to pass information to secondActivity and display the image there
      break;
      case R.id.button3 :
          Intent i= new Intent("com.example.secondActivityy");
          startActivity(i)
          //use intents to pass information to secondActivity and display the image there
      break;
    }
 }
```

To pass values using intents

On Button click

```
         Intent i= new Intent("com.example.secondActivity");
         i.puExtra("key",value);
         startActivity(i);
```

In Second Activity retrieve it as below

```
         Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras!=null)
        {
         int values= extras.getInt("key");
        }
```

Comment: The MainActivity should implements OnClickListener

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.
But I still didn't understand how is the value being passed to the secondActivity?

My initial plan was to pass some integer value(such as 1,2or3) and then use 'if-else' in the second activity to determine which image is to be displayed.

Comment: You can pass resource id of image to new activity. That is an integer and you can set that value directly to imageView

Comment: Yup you can do that. the value can be be a resource id. R.drawable.myimage

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `switch case` to determine which button was clicked by the user and show the corresponding / relevant image in the next activity? For example:

First, make your Activity implement the `OnClickListener`. Then, in the `onCreate()` cast your `Buttons` and set their `setOnClickListener`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    Button Image1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Image1);       
    Image1.setOnClickListener(this);
    .... // THE REST OF THE BUTTONS
}
```

I am assuming you are passing a `Bundle` in the Intent for starting the next Activity. Change that code to pass information that contains which button was pressed.

For example:
Intent showPhoto = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, YOUR_SECOND_ACTIVITY.class);
showPhoto.putExtra("BUTTON_CLICKED", "IMAGE1");
startActivity(showPhoto);

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // Perform action on click
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.Image1:
        // RUN THE CODE TO START THE NEXT ACTIVITY
        Intent showPhoto = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, YOUR_SECOND_ACTIVITY.class);
        showPhoto.putExtra("BUTTON_CLICKED", "IMAGE1");
        startActivity(showPhoto);

        break;
    case R.id.Image2:
        // RUN THE CODE TO START THE NEXT ACTIVITY
        Intent showPhoto = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, YOUR_SECOND_ACTIVITY.class);
        showPhoto.putExtra("BUTTON_CLICKED", "IMAGE2");
        startActivity(showPhoto);

        break;
    case R.id.Image3:
        // RUN THE CODE TO START THE NEXT ACTIVITY
        Intent showPhoto = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, YOUR_SECOND_ACTIVITY.class);
        showPhoto.putExtra("BUTTON_CLICKED", "IMAGE3");
        startActivity(showPhoto);

        break;
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have 3 buttons Image1, Image2 & Image3 on my MainActivity. Now based
>   on what button the user clicks (Image1, Image2 & Image3), a
>   corresponding image is displayed on a new activity.

=> As you already said yo know how to create buttons and initiate it.

Now you just need to assign `OnClickListener` to every buttons and then pass Image id or URL into the Intent by which you are calling new activity.

Check the code posted by @IceMAN above, now as I mentioned above, put ImageURL or Image ID into Intent by using putExtra() method.

For example:

```
 Intent intent= new Intent(CurrentClass.this, ImageActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("ImageURL",strImageURL);
  startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

For example you have 3 `Button`s and `ImageView` in `Main` layout:

Main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll_main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:text="button 1"
        />
<Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:text="button 2"
        />
<Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:text="button 3"
        />

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        />
```

I your activity metod onClick handle events from three buttons. And we need to recognize that the button has been pressed.

MyActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button btn1;
Button btn2;
Button btn3;
ImageView iv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
 }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   switch (v.getId()){
       case R.id.btn1:
       {
           Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "onClickButton1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           toast.show();
           iv.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.my_image_1);
           break;
       }
       case R.id.btn2:
       {
           Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "onClickButton2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           toast.show();
           iv.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.my_image_2);
           break;
       }
       case R.id.btn3:
       {
           Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "onClickButton3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
           toast.show();
           iv.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.my_image_3);
           break;
       }
   }
}
```

}

Where `my_image_1`, `my_image_2`, `my_image_3` - images, from your `Drawable` folder.
Hope its Help.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in onCreate of your activity that contains the 3 buttons

```
        Button image1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.image1);
        image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayImagActivity.class)
                .putExtra("ImageName", "Image1"));
            }
        });

        Button image2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.image2);
        image2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayImagActivity.class)
                .putExtra("ImageName", "Image2"));
            }
        });

        Button image3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.image3);
        image3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayImagActivity.class)
                .putExtra("ImageName", "Image3"));
            }
        });
```

Add this in onCreate of your activity where you will set the image:

```
        String imageName = getIntent().getStringExtra("ImageName");
        if(imageName.equals("Image1")) {
            //set image 1
        }
        else if(imageName.equals("Image2")) {
            //set image 2
        }
        else if(imageName.equals("Image3")) {
            //set image 3
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply implement one `ClickListener` for each button, which will start the corresponding activity. See an example [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is and old question, but there is another way, which I prefer, because you can use the same default method for all buttons.

First add a tag to each button.

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/imageOneButton"
    android:tag="1"
    android:onClick="chooseImage" />
```

Then use this tag number to alter the behavior of your method.

```
 public void chooseImage(View view) {

    int imageNumber = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());

    // I'll just send this tag number to a toast, but you can send it in your intent
    // as an "Extra"

    Toast.makeText(this, view.getTag().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```