# how to know which button called a method?

Tags: android, button

I'm using a method : button_click(View view)  to set a text on an editText , and I have a lot of buttons and each one of them should set text on a specific editText .

Is there any way to know which button called the method , so that I can set text of the correct editText ?

here is the code of the method :

```
public void button_click(View view) {

            // Create the dialog
            final Dialog mDateTimeDialog = new Dialog(view.getContext());
            // Inflate the root layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) view.getContext().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
            final RelativeLayout mDateTimeDialogView = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.datepick, null);
            // Grab widget instance
            final DateTimePicker mDateTimePicker = (DateTimePicker) mDateTimeDialogView
                    .findViewById(R.id.DateTimePicker);
            mDateTimePicker.setDateChangedListener(this);

            // Update demo edittext when the "OK" button is clicked
            ((Button) mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.SetDateTime))
                    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            mDateTimePicker.clearFocus();
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            String result_string = mDateTimePicker.getMonth()
                                    + "/"
                                    + String.valueOf(mDateTimePicker.getDay())
                                    + "/"
                                    + String.valueOf(mDateTimePicker.getYear())
                                    + "  "
                                    + String.valueOf(mDateTimePicker.getHour())
                                    + ":"
                                    + String.valueOf(mDateTimePicker.getMinute());

                            edit_text1.setText(result_string);
                            mDateTimeDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

            // Cancel the dialog when the "Cancel" button is clicked
            ((Button) mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.CancelDialog))
                    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            mDateTimeDialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            // Reset Date and Time pickers when the "Reset" button is clicked

            ((Button) mDateTimeDialogView.findViewById(R.id.ResetDateTime))
                    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            mDateTimePicker.reset();
                        }
                    });

            // Setup TimePicker
            // No title on the dialog window
            mDateTimeDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            // Set the dialog content view
            mDateTimeDialog.setContentView(mDateTimeDialogView);
            // Display the dialog
            mDateTimeDialog.show();
        }
```

Comment: The `View` passed into the `onClick` is a reference to the View/Button that was clicked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942614/how-to-obtain-and-pass-the-value-of-a-button/15942680#15942680. check the link. you can get the id of the view clicked in your case button

Comment: @kyokotsu glad the link helped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The passed `View` is actually the button. All you need to do is switch the ID like so:

```
switch (view.getId()) {
case R.id.button1:
    // Do something here related to button 1
    break;
case R.id.button2:
    // Do something here related to button 2
    break;
}
```

Edit: Typo

Answer (score 4):

the View you clicked upone is the argument of the `onClick`. If you need its id you can retrieve it through

```
int id = view.getId();
```

in this way you can switch upon the R.id.yourButtonId to understand which has been clicked

Answer (score 2):

You're in luck - the `View view` that is passed to your handler is the actual view that was clicked.  So the view itself is the button.  Check out the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html).

Answer (score 0):

In this method you have passed view which fired event `(Button)v` should give you reference

```
public void onClick(View v)
```